# How do I make an activity the first activity launched but only on the first run of the application

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I need my app to have one activity(Register) be the first activity launched when an app is first installed but then after the initial run it will have a different activity(LogInActivity) be the first activity launched... I have put code in that makes the Register activity only run once but I can't figure out how to alter my manifest to get the desired results. I have tried moving the MAIN action to the Register activity but that causes it to be launched everytime I run my app. When the MAIN action is in the LogInActivity then Register doesn't run at all. I also tried to add a DEFAULT action in my manifest under the opposite activity of where I had the MAIN action but that didn't work either and upon further research of what DEFAULT does I don't believe this is what I need. So is there some other intent I need to add to my XML?

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/skey"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

 ///////////FIND INFO ACTIVITY
    <activity
        android:name=".FindInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LogInActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  //////////LOG IN ACTIVITY
    <activity
        android:name=".LogInActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LogInActivity" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  //////////REGISTER ACTIVITY
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LogInActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have three separate LAUNCHER activities unless you want the user to be able to launch the app from the homescreen from three separate items (there are valid use-cases for this, but this isn't it).

Have one activity that handles launching the application.  It checks the boolean in your SharePreferences, then starts the appropriate activity from there. Then just finish the Activity so the user won't re-open it when the user presses "Back".

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     if (firstTimeRunning()) {
         // start register activity.
     } else {
         // start login activity.
     }
     finish();
   }
}
```

In the Manifest just have this Activity as:

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You don't need any IntentFilters for your register activity or login activity because these are never opened through implicit intents, nor do they have any special permissions (from what I can see).

Comment: So you're saying that I need to make the activity which I want to launch everytime the MAIN and check the sharedpreferences in that same activity?

Comment: Yes.  You can't change the Manifest.

Comment: well that worked... at least in the emulator.. i'm about to try an install on a real device but my question now is how will the app know to launch the Register activiy first when the app is first ran? I get how it knows to run LogInActivity first the rest of the time but confused.

Comment: Logically, it'll work like this.  When the app is first installed, there are no SharePreferences or local storage for the app. If you check your status, it will return false meaning that either the boolean wasn't set or the user never opened the app. In the Register Activity, let the user do whatever (s)he has to do, then set the boolean in SharePreferences to true.  Then, from then on, that boolean will always be true.

Comment: Of course, if they reinstall the app or wipe out the data, the user will go through the registration again.  This can't be solved within the app and would require a server solution (also it's not a big deal 99.9% of the time).

Comment: This works on the emulator but when I install on a real device the Register activity does not start.

Answer (score 1):

Use **SharedPreference**. When you open the app the first time do this:

```
SharedPreferences shared;
shared=getSharedPreferences("com.example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
shared.edit().putBoolean("first_time",true).apply();
```

in your `onCreate()` of first Activity do this:

```
SharedPreferences shared;
shared=getSharedPreferences("com.example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(shared.getBoolean("first_time",false)){
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NewFirstActivity.class));
finish();
}
```

Is the easiest way to "storage" data and states. SharedPreference also works with Strings, Int values, etc (if you don't want boolean value)

Comment: I already have the shared preferences set up... please read the entire post before trying to answer the question,.. in my post I state:  I have put code in that makes the Register activity only run once but I can't figure out how to alter my manifest to get the desired results.

Comment: but you can't... you have only 1 launch activity and declare the rest... they doesn't even have an order (if you want to only open ones). That's why a SharedPreference is the best option to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Manifest` you should have only one launcher class, in the same class's `onCreate` method check for already logged in condition (`SharedPreference`). If yes, then using `Intent` launch HomeActivity otherwise launch LoginActivity if the user has registered and logged out. When user logs in, save account id / session details / user details in `SharedPreference` which you can validate in your launcher class for starting specific activity.

Comment: I thought that the launcher was required in order for the class to launch period. I still need the other classes to launch just not first. I thought MAIN controlled what launched first?

Comment: @thatdude1087, Your understanding was wrong. Launcher is for each icon that appears in the launcher. If you had two launcher activities, then two launcher icons would appear in the main Android launcher. If you had three, then three icons would appear in your launcher, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As Mariano said, you can use SharedPreferences. If you don't want to open your settings at startup you can use a Dialog to let the user decide to go to your settings or do nothing.

By the way, I think that use SharedPreferences to store login information (username and password) is best practice than be asking these values every time you start an app.