# Creating a registering kind of app

Tags: android

How do i create an app in which the launcher activity is displayed for the first time when the app is used for the first time and after that it displays a different activity and thus different xml

Comment: User SharedPreference

Comment: Please refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As Mrinmoy already mentioned in the comments, use a boolean in the `SharedPreferences` to keep track of whether or not the app is launched for the first time. Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976382/how-do-i-make-an-activity-the-first-activity-launched-but-only-on-the-first-run) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SharedPreferences or SQLite for saving whether launcher activity has been viewed or not and next time you open up the application, you can just check it and take it to different screen accordingly.